# Center-parent Not working when called from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

On the code below when the FormWaitingForm is called from the UI thread via `buttonBusy_Click`, `formWaitingForm` loads in the center
 of the main form as expected. However when called from the `BackgroundWorker` via `buttonBusyWorkerThread_Click`, it loads in the 
 center of the PC screen. How can I fix this ?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    WaitingForm formWaitingForm;
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker(); // Backgroundworker
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Define event handlers
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ProcessTick);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void buttonBusy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This starts in the center of the parent as expected
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        formWaitingForm = new WaitingForm();
        formWaitingForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        formWaitingForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void buttonBusyWorkerThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This does not start in the center of the parent
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // starts the background worker
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    { }

    private void ProcessTick(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // This does not start in the center of the parent
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        formWaitingForm = new WaitingForm();
        formWaitingForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        formWaitingForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: @OP you're creating multiple UI threads.  Don't do this. Use a single UI thread throughout your application.  Also, don't block your UI thread by calling `Thread.Sleep` in it.

Comment: @Servy i cannot initiate from the main thread in my actual application as i have a filsystemwatcher that triggers my app to do work - It is that method (which does not run in the main UI) that needs to show my busy form. The example above is just a simple representation of this. Any ideas ?

Comment: You do what you always do when you want to update the UI from a non-UI thread.  There are literally millions of resources on the web that describe how to handle this situation.

Comment: agreed i invoke but my question isnt that at all - the centreparent isnt working...

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer your question.  If I was, I would have posted an answer.  I was telling you that is a **very** bad idea to create multiple UI threads, which is what you are currently doing.  Rather than find a way of centering your form while still showing it from a separate thread, you should use a single UI thread, to save yourself a world of hurt down the road.  Move onto your issue of centering the form *after* you've done that.

Comment: @Servy filesystemwatcher doesnt kick off in the UI thread or am i wrong?

Comment: Correct, it does not.  As I said before.  There are many, many, many resources out there that explain to you how to run code in the UI thread when you are currently executing in a non-UI thread.

Comment: @Servy i have done more research onto my issue - my question is so different to what i thought that i made a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364525/centerparent-not-working-when-parent-does-not-have-focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormStartPosition.CenterParent` applies to the parent of MDI forms, not to the **owner** form. Therefore it will have no effect on non-MDI forms.

You can use these extension methods to open a form centerd to its owner form:

```
public static void ShowCentered(this Form frm, Form owner)
{
    Rectangle ownerRect = GetOwnerRect(frm, owner);
    frm.Location = new Point(ownerRect.Left + (ownerRect.Width - frm.Width) / 2,
                             ownerRect.Top + (ownerRect.Height - frm.Height) / 2);
    frm.Show(owner);
}

public static void ShowDialogCentered(this Form frm, Form owner)
{
    Rectangle ownerRect = GetOwnerRect(frm, owner);
    frm.Location = new Point(ownerRect.Left + (ownerRect.Width - frm.Width) / 2,
                             ownerRect.Top + (ownerRect.Height - frm.Height) / 2);
    frm.ShowDialog(owner);
}

private static Rectangle GetOwnerRect(Form frm, Form owner)
{
    return owner != null ? owner.DesktopBounds : Screen.GetWorkingArea(frm);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
formWaitingForm.ShowDialogCentered(owner);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not call it from a non-ui thread. Any windows based UI 101: only the creating thread can change the object.

in the background thread, use Invoke to invoke back into the UI thread.