# CenterParent not working when parent does not have focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a timer.The timer loads a dialog to show that the form is busy. When the main form does not have focus, the busy form is loaded in the top left of the pc screen (Which is not expected). When the form has focus it works as expected. If set ShowInTaskbar to true then it does work as expected even when the main form does not have focus. What is going on here and how can i fix ?

**C# Code**

```
namespace CenterParentIssue
{

    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        WaitingForm formWindowsWaitingForm;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formWindowsWaitingForm = new WaitingForm();
            formWindowsWaitingForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            formWindowsWaitingForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            formWindowsWaitingForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `WaitingForm` a parent context. [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload which takes a Window as an argument, this window is the parent/owner.

```
//...
formWindowsWaitingForm.ShowDialog(this);
//...
```